# Prestashop V1.6 - my RowAction "mail" is not working

Tags: email, prestashop

Hi there dear developers. I have made a custom AddRowAction named "Mail" for my list of product keys in my custom backoffice module. It almost works except that the content of this action hook is not triggered. For testing I put a default mail() function to test if it works. But it doesn't work in my processMail(). Mail does work when I change the button to Export.

This what i have made today:

My backoffice controller: **WORKS FINE**

```
class AdminAvantokeyLogController extends ModuleAdminController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->table = 'avanto_log';
        $this->className = "AvantoLog";
        $this->_defaultOrderBy = 'id_avanto_log';

        $this->addRowAction('edit');
        $this->addRowAction('delete');
        $this->addRowAction('mail');  //this is my custom button


        $this->bulk_actions = array('delete' => array('text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
            'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?')), );

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_avanto_log' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Key ID'),
                'width' => 20,
            ),
            'serial_key' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Serial Keys'),
                'width' => 200,
            ),
            'product_name' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Product Name'),
                'width' => 50,
            ),

        );

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

This is the displayMaillink method in the same controller: **WORKS FINE**

```
public function displayMailLink($token, $id)
{
    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array(
            'href' => self::$currentIndex.'&token='.$this->token.'&'.$this->identifier.'='.$id.'&mail'.$this->table.'=1',
            'action' => $this->l('Mail')
        )
    );
    $content = $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . "avanto_key/views/templates/admin/list_action_test.tpl");
    return $content;
}
```

This processMail() method is not triggered when clicking the Mail button :

```
public function processMail()
{
    mail("info@customit.be" , "test message from export" , "this is my message content");
}
```

Can someone just point me in the right direction? I have copied the methods from Admincontroller and the build in exportcontroller. But I doesn't get triggered. Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For default actions add, edit, delete, view, export etc. the AdminController class will detect and parse an action from GET parameters, but for custom actions you need to define the action property in the controller yourself in order for the `processAction()` to be called.

```php
public function initProcess()
{
    parent::initProcess();
    if (Tools::getIsset('mail' . $this->table) {
        $this->action = 'mail';
    }
}
```

Now that your custom action is defined, AdminController can [call](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/controller/AdminController.php#L922) your process action method.

Comment: hi there TheDrot. You are amazing. It was indeed this piece of code that was missing. Now I understand it. The this->action is refering to the code which I have put in the processMail(). thanks soo much!!!